# Migration from .cshtml to *.razor

Tags: javascript, razor

It's possible to use Url.Content and scripts in DummyPage.razor? It's necessary to implement the code from DummyPage.cshtml to DummyPage.razor.

```html
@page "/apidocumentation"
<div class="container-flex">
    <div class="col-lg-12 control-section">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <rapi-doc spec-url="@Url.Content("doc/api/dummy.json")"></rapi-doc>

                <section Scripts>
                    <script src="@Url.Content("lib/rapidoc/dummy.js")"></script>
                </section>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need inject **IJSRuntime** for JS. It allows to load JavaScript code to your component.

If your JS function has a specific name, you can call with these function: `InvokeAsync/InvokeVoidAsync`.

**Example:**

---

Add script tag in your _Host.cshtml
(P.S. `~` is equal to your `wwwroot` folder)

```
...
<script src="~/js/myJS.js"></script>
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

myJS.js

```
function MyScript(name) {
    return "Hello " + name;
}
```

Test.razor

```
@page "/test"
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<p id="myId">@Text</p>
<button @onclick="OnClick">Submit</button>

@code {
    private string Text { get; set; }

    private async void OnClick()
    {
        var exampleText = "World!";
        try
        {
            Text = await JS.InvokeAsync<string>("MyScript", exampleText);
        }
        catch(JSException ex)
        {
            Text = ex.Message;
        }

        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Example after pushed the button:
[image: Example output with JS]

If your JS script use a function `onload` (for example), you could override and use the OnAfterRenderAsync function.

```
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        //invoke only one time, after your component is loaded
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("onload");
        }
        
    }
```

I don't know rapi-doc, maybe you could pass the json through backend with a variable.